# Botão com link no MVC5 não está funcionando

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5, controller, popup

Criei um popup em um projeto mvc5 (Razor) e não esta funcionando o link que quando clicasse no botão iria para outra pagina mas não está funcionando vou postar o código aqui abaixo.

**Código :**

```
<div id="banner_popup" style="display:none">
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="fecha_banner();" class="linksFechar">
        <img class="imgfechar" src="~/Images/Popup/fechar.png" border="0">
    </a>
   <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("TornarPagina", new { controller = "HomeController", action = "TornarPagina" })" title="Clique Aqui!">
        <div class="info">
            <h1><span class="linha1">Faça o </span></br><span class="linha2a"> ABC </span><span class="linha2b">do</span><span class="linha2c"> ABC </span></br><span class="linha3">sua página Inicial!</span></h1>
            <div class="button">
                Clique Aqui!
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
        if(document.getElementById('banner_popup'))
            abre_banner();
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var banner = sessionStorage.getItem('banner_popup');
        if (banner != "1") {
            abre_banner();
            sessionStorage.setItem('banner_popup', "1");
        }
    });

    function fecha_banner_timeout() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            fecha_banner()
        }, 10000);
    }

    function abre_banner() {
        var banner_obj = document.getElementById('banner_popup');

        banner_obj.style.left = '';
        banner_obj.style.top = '';  

        banner_obj.style.display = '';

        fecha_banner_timeout();
    }

    function fecha_banner() {
        var banner_obj = document.getElementById('banner_popup');
        banner_obj.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Observação: Já fiz o controller que está na HomeController fiz uma actionResult que vai retorna a view, e a view explica o popup.

Comment: Como fica o link no HTML gerado?

Comment: Ele da um erro quando executa mas no html =  href="~/Views/Home/TornarPagina.cshtml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é preciso usar `@Url.RouteUrl` para o seu caso. Use no lugar [`@Url.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String%29):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("TornarPagina", "Home", new { alt = "Clique Aqui!" })">
   ...
```

Não se usa "Controller" no nome do *Controller*. Apenas `"Home"` já resolve corretamente.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado deixa te perguntar  tem que ser Home ? mas obrigado

Comment: "Home" é o *Controller* que se deseja apontar o link. Pode ser outro, mas sem o `"Controller"` escrito no final. [Aproveite e veja este link para entender como funciona o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!